# hammer:hammer swiperight with Meteor blaze template not firing

Tags: javascript, meteor, hammer.js

This Meteor template event `swiperight` does not fire but when it it changed to `mousemove` if fires OK.
Meteor: 1.4.1.1
hammer:hammer: 2.0.4_2

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'swiperight .swipe.active': function(event) {  //<-- works with mousemove
    alert('swipped');
  }
});
```

I also tried to add this code in:

```js
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
  $('body').hammer({
    drag_min_distance:1,
    swipe_velocity:0.1
  });
};
```

Any idea what to do to get this to work? Thanks